# Dependency Injection of open generics with arguments

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320265/how-to-inject-dependencies-of-generics-in-asp-net-core) article talks about how to register Generic interfaces in .Net Core. However I have a generic interface which has multiple arguments and am having trouble figuring out registeration and constructor injection.

My Interface has 4 arguments

```
public class TestImplementation 
{
    // Try to inject IRepository here ??????
    public TestImplementation(.......)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository<Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4> 
{
    ...
}

public interface IRepository<T, U, V, W> where T : ITemplate1 where U : ITemplate2,...  
{
    ...
}
```

If I try to inject the Interface to any class, it gives me error as the interface doesnt get resolved even using below code in other part of the code

```
services.GetService(typeof(IRepository<,,,>))
```

I tried using constructor injection but it makes compiler unhappy (Unable to resolve service for type '....Interface....' while attempting to activate xxxx) as I want to keep the Interface open. I however resolve the interface in the code

Comment: Your code at the moment contains invalid syntax, so it's a little difficult to see how this is not a duplicate of [the question you link to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320265/how-to-inject-dependencies-of-generics-in-asp-net-core). `TestRepository : Repository<Test>` is not possible as `Repository` is not a generic class. `Repository` implements `IRepository` but doesn't seem to specify the types required by the interface.

Comment: I cleaned the code to represent the problem

Comment: Inspired from the answer in the linked question, this should work: `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4>), typeof(Repository));` and then in the constructor: `public TestImplementation(IRepository<Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4> repo)`

Comment: You cannot `services.GetService(typeof(IRepository<,,,>))` because the service you're getting has to be a _constructed_ generic type, i.e. it has to have all of the type parameters specified, e.g. `services.GetService(typeof(IRepository<int, string, float, bool>))`. If you just want to register a constructed generic type with the container then that's easy: `services.AddScoped<IRepository<int, string, float, bool>, MyRepositoryImpl>()`. If you want to register open generics with the container, you'll need a more advanced DI framework like Autofac.

Comment: Oops, I'm wrong - you can register open generics with something like `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<,,,>), typeof(MyRepositoryImpl<,,,>))`. I'd assume that the number of generic type params have to match for both the service type and the implementation type.

Comment: The injection does not throw any error but constructor doesnt resolve the dependency. Also, I cannot provide TestImplementation(IRepository<Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4> repo) as I do not know whether ITemplate1 got resolved by Test1 or something else. I want to do TestImplementation(IRepository<ITemplate1, ITemplate2, ITemplate3, ITemplate4> repo) but that doesnt work

Comment: Just a thought on usability: with that number of generic parameters I think it's not easy for the clients to figure out the typisation they need. How about an IRepositoryFactory that you can inject everywhere without caring about parameters and that write something like var r = factory.Create...()?

Comment: This would mean removing DI as it doesnt make sense to implement both in parallel when complex objects are resolved manually and Unit Test project refers to the factory. I believe there has to be a way to resolve this

Comment: How about further segregating your interfaces and concerns by creating an `IBaseRepository` that has a child `Repository`. Then having your additional concerns of `IRepository<T, U, V, W>` inherit from `IBaseRepository`. Anyone who implements `IRepository<T, U, V, W>` may also inherit basic repo implementations from `Repository`. The DI should then be able to resolve each abstraction easily including `IBaseRepository` if `Repository` is concrete. You can then have specific implementations for `IRepository<Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4>` or `IRepository<Test4, Test3, Test2, Test1>` etc.

Comment: Take a look at the Scrutor library. This makes advanced DI a lot easier. I believe it has support for your scenario. I believe there are (closed) issues about having open generic support

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper way is to not inject the `Repository` Service. It should just be used as a template with functionality. You then create an additional class that inherits from the `Repository` class and an interface that inherits from `IRepository`. That way you can assign the values of the generic values and then inject it in a neat and controlled way.

At first this pattern might seem like a bit of extra work, but it allows for custom functionality for each table repository, keeps it clear which table you are working with and allows for easy replacement for different databases. See example below:

So as you had it, create your `Repository` and `IRepository` interface:

```
public abstract class Repository<T, U, V, W> : IRepository<T, U, V, W> 
{
    ...
}

public interface IRepository<T, U, V, W> where T : ITemplate1 where U : ITemplate2,...  
{
    ...
}
```

Now create an interface for your specific table. First the interface:

```
public interface ISomeTableRepository : IRepository<input_1, input_2, ...> {}
```

Now create the class repository:

```
public class SomeTableRepository : Repository<input_1, input_2,...> , ISomeTableRepository {}
```

Now you register these the new repository that doesn't have inputs in your `Startup.cs` file.

```
services.AddScoped<ISomeTableRepository, SomeTableRepository> ();
```

Now you can easily inject it without the need to add parameters:

```
public class TestImplementation 
{
    readonly ISomeTableRepository _someTable;

    
    public TestImplementation(ISomeTableRepository someTable)
    {
        _someTable = someTable;
    }
}
```

---

## Method 2

This answer seems to be getting a fair bit of views, and it is something I wrote a while ago. Below as another method for doing DPI. I still recommend the method above if you need reliability and performance, but for a quick method you can use `unbound` dependency injection.

So as you had it, create your `Repository` and `IRepository` interface:

```
public abstract class Repository<T, U, V, W> : IRepository<T, U, V, W> 
{
    ...
}

public interface IRepository<T, U, V, W> where T : ITemplate1 where U : ITemplate2,...  
{
    ...
}
```

Now register the interfaces as unbound in your startup or program file:

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IRepository<,,,>), typeof(Repository<,,,>)>
```

Note that the number of inputs/variables should correlate to the number of empty spaces between the `<...>` So if there is 1 input it will be `<>`. If there are two: `<,>` and if there are three `<,,>` and so forth.

Answer (score -1):

Whichever members you need to have in the unbound generic type you put into a base type which the derived type implements.

You can use either `object` or `dynamic` for the values of an unknown type.

See this example:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    object TV { get; set; }
    object UV { get; set; }
    object VV { get; set; }
    object WV { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T, U, V, W>: IRepository
{
    object IRepository.TV { get => TV; set => TV = (T)value; }
    object IRepository.UV { get => UV; set => UV = (U)value; }
    object IRepository.VV { get => VV; set => VV = (V)value; }
    object IRepository.WV { get => WV; set => WV = (W)value; }
    new T TV { get; set; }
    new U UV { get; set; }
    new V VV { get; set; }
    new W WV { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can do:

```
services.GetService(typeof(IRepository))
```

without any issue.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/kwoOOe